# Can I use regular expressions with guard-concat?

Tags: ruby, guard

I'm using the guard-concat plugin for guard to concatenate my handlebar template files.

Can I use regular expression to make it concat all files in one folder instead of typing in all the names of the files?

so instead of doing this:

```
guard :concat, type: "php", files: %w(a b b/c b/d), input_dir: "app/views/handlebars",     output: "app/views/handlebars/all"
```

I could do this:

```
guard :concat, type: "php", files: %r{.+}, input_dir: "app/views/handlebars", output: "app/views/handlebars/all"
```

When I do that I get the following error:

```
ERROR - Invalid Guardfile, original error is: > [#] undefined method `join' for /.+/:Regexp
```

Comment: Could you try `files: [/.+\.php$/]`?

Comment: files: [/.+\.php$/] does not give me an error but also does not concatenate any files (doesn't work). Maybe because the extension (php) should not be included.

files: [/.+/] gives me this error:
**ERROR - Guard::Concat failed to achieve its <run_on_changes>, exception was: > [#] Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument app/views/handlebars/(?-mix:.+).php**. Thank you for the reply btw

Comment: Ah, this should most probably work: `files: ['.+']`

Comment: Hi Dogbert, Still got an error saying: `ERROR - Guard::Concat failed to achieve its <run_on_changes>, exception was: > [#] Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - app/views/handlebars/.+.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Francesco Canessa (responsible for guard-concat) has told me

> I can implement this feature but usually the files order is important
>   both for CSS and JS (for example for code that needs libraries to be
>   loaded first)

So this is not possible today but might be added in future releases.

[link to the issue on guard-concat github page](https://github.com/makevoid/guard-concat/issues/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Dir#glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) (or it alias `Dir#[]`):

```
Dir['*/**.php']
```

as argument. It will return array containing all files with `.php` extension in all subfolders.

Comment: `guard :concat, type: "php", files: Dir['*/**.php'], input_dir: "public/templates", output: "app/views/handlebars/all"` will not produce any errors but there it does not concatenate the files either. As far as I can see this does not work, am I doing something wrong? Thanks for the suggestion. –